# Compiler version incompatibility nightmare

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, tokens, compiler

I'm new to Solidity and Truffle.  I'm trying to compile my Solidity code within Truffle to create an ERC-20 token. I have `@truffle/hdwallet-provider` and `@openzeppelin/contracts` as my dependencies. Now, I only have two Solidity files, both of which have `pragma solidity ^0.6.0;`.  I have been uninstalling and reinstalling to different versions and changing the compiler version in `truffle-config.js` to whichever the error message is telling me to change as well as changing the pragma solidity versions in the two files I have.  I also had to change the individual files in node modules to fit the right version.

Finally, I think the change in the version from `^0.6.2` to `^0.6.0` broke a file called `Address.sol` in the utility folder of contracts in Node Modules:

```
    function sendValue(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) internal {
        require(address(this).balance >= amount, "Address: insufficient balance");

        (bool success, ) = recipient.call{ value: amount }(""); // here
        require(success, "Address: unable to send value, recipient may have reverted");
    }
```

The error message shows:

> ParserError: Expected ';' but got '{'

indicating the point right after `call`.

First, how do I fix this? And second, is this version incompatibility issue what I should expect every time there's been updates in either Truffle, Solidity, or any of my dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the compilation stopped working is because that way of performing a `call` was only made available in [Solidity `0.6.2`](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.6.2):

> Allow gas and value to be set in external function calls using `c.f{gas: 10000, value: 4 ether}()`.

Prior to `0.6.2`, you had to use `c.gas(_gasLimit).value(_value)(_data);`

This change is simply an added feature and not a breaking change. You can use the latter `call` format for *any* version of solidity, both pre- and post- `0.6.2`. The new version was introduced as a convenience and not as a mandatory way to do it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. So how do I reformat `(bool success, ) = recipient.call{ value: amount }("");`?

Comment: I believe you can do it like this: `recipient.call.value(amount)("");`